# How to convert getopt-based cli php script to a web ($_GET) one?

Tags: php, get, console, command-line-interface, getopt

So I have this getopt-based cli php script and this getopt function in it:

```
function get_cli_params() {
$params = getopt( 'g', array( 'xpub:', 'xpubfile:',
                              'outfile:',
                              'derivation:',
                              'numsig:',
                              'format:', 'cols:',
                              'gap-limit:',
                              'logfile:', 'loglevel:',
                              'toshi:',
                              'blockchaindotinfo:',
                              'btcd:',
                              'btcdotcom:',
                              'blockcypher:',
                              'insight:',
                              'api:',.
                              'list-cols',
                              'oracle-raw:', 'oracle-json:',
                              'include-unused',
                              'gen-only:', 'type:',
                              'batch-size:',
                              'version', 'help',
                              ) );

return $params;}
```

It works well this way from console:

```
$ ./hd-wallet-addrs.php -g --xpub=xpub6BfKpqjTwvH21wJGWEfxLppb8sU7C6FJge2kWb9315oP4ZVqCXG29cdUtkyu7YQhHyfA5nt63nzcNZHY
```

How can I convert this script to a web one? I want to open it online and pass arguments to it via $_GET. Thank you.

PS: Script page: https://github.com/dan-da/hd-wallet-addrs

Comment: Just replace with `return $_GET;` and access as `http://example.com/hd-wallet-addrs.php?g& xpub=xpub6BfKpqjTwvH21wJGWEfxLppb8sU7C6FJge2kWb9315oP4ZVqCXG29cdUtkyu7YQhHyfA5nt63nzcNZHY` may have to teek the array, use `print_r` to see it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem.